# Delete a full document

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to delete a full document in a collection.
I have a collection called "pushes", every document inside gets an auto generate id from firebase.
I use this code to listen to create event of pushes:

```
    functions.firestore.document('pushes/{msgId}').onCreate(ev => {

   });
```

Everything works well I send my push but I want to delete this request.
I tried this code:

```
admin.firestore().doc('pushes/'+querySnapshot.id)).delete();
```

Still doesn't work, I tried also to use the "where" query but I don't know the auto document id key to compare:

```
admin.firestore().collection('pushes').where('<WHAT HERE?????>', '==', id).get().delete()
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Can you try `admin.firestore().collection('pushes').doc(querySnapshot.id)).delete();`? What's the value of `querySnapshot.id`?

Comment: Well I finally succeed to delete it with: ev.ref.delete();